# How does mdfind (filename) pattern matching work? Punctuation in the search string gives non-intuitive results

Tags: macos, command-line, spotlight

1. There are multiple ways to use `mdfind` to find files with a given name; here are two that work in some cases:

```
mdfind -name barfoo
mdfind "kMDItemFSName == '*barfoo*'c"
```

The former finds files named `barfoo`, `barfoo suffix`, `barfoosuffix`, `prefix barfoo`, and `prefix barfoo suffix` -- but neither `barfoosuffix` nor `prefixbarfoosuffix`.
The latter finds all seven of these.

**Why does the `-name` version not find the last two?**

---

2. However, including an underscore (or other punctuation) completely goofs up the `kMDItemFSName` version:

```
mdfind -name barfoo_
mdfind "kMDItemFSName == '*barfoo_*'c"
```

The former again finds `barfoo_`, `barfoo_ suffix`, `barfoo_suffix`, `prefix barfoo_`, and `prefix barfoo_ suffix` -- but neither `barfoo_suffix` nor `prefixbarfoo_suffix`. (Consistent, but Q1 applies here also.)

The latter finds none of the seven.

**Why does the underscore (or other punctuation such as a comma) break the `kMDItemFSName` search?**

---

3. If one replaces barfoo_ with _barfoo, then *both* `mdfind` versions find *all seven* of `_barfoo`, `_barfoo suffix`, `_barfoosuffix`, `prefix _barfoo`, `prefix _barfoo suffix`, `_barfoosuffix`, and `prefix_barfoosuffix`.

**Why does a leading underscore change the `-name` version's results?**

And, **why is the leading underscore different from the trailing underscore for the `kMDItemFSName` version?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001843-BBCFBCAG doesn't mention any special meaning of `_` or punctation characters.

Comment: @Thinkr The main question here seems to be "how does pattern matching work in `mdfind`".

Comment: @Thinkr Edited title to try to reframe the question.

Comment: Searching for `bar_foo` seems to work in a manner consistent with `barfoo`. So there must be something about the trailing underscore before the asterisk.

Comment: Are you certain that file contains the metadata you’re searching?  Check the file with the command `mdls  -name kMDItemFSName  foo.bar`

Comment: Yep. `touch barfoo_` then `mdls -name kMDItemFSName barfoo_` returns `kMDItemFSName = "barfoo_"` but `mdfind "kMDItemFSName == '*barfoo_*'c"` returns nothing.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but that metadata tag doesn’t officially exist.  Therefore, there’s no data for which you can search again. See [kMDItemTitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kmditemtitle). It’s the closest metadata tag I can find

Comment: Yes, it exists.  See [kMDItemFSName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/kmditemfsname?language=objc).

Comment: @ErikJohnson Thanks, that's clearer :)